# Syntatically correct alternative for `return || throw`

Tags: javascript

I have tried to use this code:

```
let results = await getResults();
return results || throw new Error('Error fetching results.');
```

However, this is invalid syntax because `throw` is not an expression.

What would be a syntactically correct, yet concise alternative in ES7 for this code?

I've tried this but also failed:

```
results ? return results : throw new Error('Error fetching results.');
```

Comment: Without any tricks, `if .. else`. Or in this particular case just `if (!results) throw; return;`

Comment: Error can be thrown in `getResults()` function